# Discrete logarithm over prime modulo: small input, large exponent, larger prime

Tags: discrete-logarithm, one-way-function, trapdoor

I am considering using modular exponentiation as a one-way hash function. More specifically, here is the scenario.

1) Input ($m$): the input messages are small (16-bit)

2) Exponent ($e$): the exponent is a 160-bit integer, chosen only once, and randomly; the exponent is not public

3) Prime ($p$): a 2048 bit safe prime, chosen only once and is public

The hash of the message is then computed as: $h=m^e$ mod $p$.

My question is whether there exists efficient algorithms to compute the exponent $e$ given a certain $h$, especially since there are only $2^{16}$ possibilities for $m$?

Comment: That would not be a hash as usually defined, since part of its definition ($e$) is secret. Rather, that's a keyed one-way function; it is the encryption part of a cipher if $\gcd(e,p-1)=1$

Comment: @fgrieu Agreed: keyed one-way function. Say I choose $e$ to be relatively prime to $p-1$, which I believe narrows down the possibilities for $e$. Does the small input space provide any advantage in computing $e$?

Comment: Carefully consider properties such as H(m1⋅m2)≡H(m1)⋅H(m2). They may be problematic for a hash function.

Answer (score 1):

Since attacker does not know $m$, he can't directly apply discrete logarithm methods. On the other hand, small message space allows to run discrete log algorithm on each possible $m$.

There are subexponential algorithms for dlog, but I am not sure if they are directly applicable here. But the general BSGS algorithm will find $e$ in $sqrt(e)$ operations, so for each $m$ candidate we need $~2^{80}$ operations to find some possible $e$ (total $~2^96$ complexity). Notably, most of the wrong candidated for $m$ will not yield any $e$ so this can also be used to "unhash" your "hash". Though complexity is quite high, there are high chances that more effective discrete logarithm can be applied.

Another note: assuming you use odd $e$, this "hash" leaks some information about the message: Legendre symbol (e.g. if the message is quadratic residue mod p or not).

PS: It's not completely clear how you are going to use it and why your attack model assumes only knowledge of $h$, not $m$ (since even then finding $e$ is hard). But this confuses as it may seem that you want also to hide information about $m$, which is really a bad idea here.

Answer (score 0):

That is definitely not a good hash function, but as you already realized, it is not a hash function actually. Your construction can be seen as [PRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family) or an [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code), and for both it is not secure either. A general problem is, that you allow the attacker way too little. Giving him only $h$, that's similar to a ciphertext only attack, which is just not enough in today's understanding of security.

Basically, in both cases a PRF and a HMAC you would allow the attacker access to an oracle, and challenge him with distinguishing it from a truly random function. And that is simple: $h(1)=1$  (and $h(0)=0$) in your construction, and that is easy to distinguish.

And finally: $2^{16}$ as input space is way too easy for a full search. Any modern computer can do this in seconds I guess. Especially you only have to ask for the hashes of all prime numbers in the input range, since your scheme is multiplicative: $h(x_1x_2) = h(x_1)h(x_2)$

Comment: Terminology nitpick: HMAC is a specific MAC algorithm (or, rather, a method of constructing a MAC from a cryptographic hash), of which this method is not an instance of. It's not really meaningful to ask whether something is "an HMAC", since only HMAC is an HMAC. You *could* ask whether this algorithm is a MAC (i.e. whether it satisfies the relevant unforgeability properties), though.